# Saving the states of JavaFX controls on exit

Tags: javafx-2

I have a bunch of control objects (TextBoxes, to be precise) that get injected into my code using the @FXML annotation during the FXML load.

I would like to save the states of these controls, specifically the text values, when the user closes the Scene by clicking the close box on the title bar.

However, when I trap the CloseRequest event in an OnCloseRequest handler I find that the values of the control variables are null (the original injection works, so this is something that happens in between the loading of the FXML and the calling of OnCloseRequest).

Can anyone explain this behavior and/or suggest how I can get the functionality that I want?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCloseRequest` is

> Called when there is an external request to close this Window. ...

(from Javadoc). One of the meanings of "external request" is when you close the window through OS native window close button. The `closeRequest` event is not triggered through the programmatic `stage.close()` or `stage.hide()` calls. So consider to handle [onHiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onHidingProperty) or [onHidden](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onHiddenProperty) events.

Otherwise post your OnCloseRequest handler code.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to try onHidden out to see whether it gives the behavior I'm after.  The name makes it sound like it would get called any time the windows is occluded, but the JavaDoc makes it sound more like it gets called only when the window is closed.  If it's the former then it's not the behavior I want and if it's the latter then it's an unusually bad choice of name.

Comment: If you are closing the `Stage` then the [stage.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close()) is equivalent to stage.hide().